# Conditional Select Menus Second On Change doesn't fire

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="a">
    <option>Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">hello</option>
</select>
<div id="second_select"></div>

<script>
    $( '#a' ).change(function() {
    var data='<select id="b"><option>Please Select</option><option value="1">hello hello</option></select>';
        $('#second_select').html(data);
    });
</script>
<script>
    $( '#b' ).change(function() {
    alert('hello');
    });
</script>
```

[Sample on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1w685pk/)

This is just a sample.

*The second menu is generated from an ajax post success which I think is unrelated.

Any comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the reason is, that you try to bind the eventListener (change) before the second select is inserted into the DOM. So you would have to set the second eventListener inside the first eventListener-callback.

Comment: How can I fix that? The document ready function was posted by mistake which is not on the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the second eventListener inside the callback of first onChange-Listener.
Otherwise you set an eventListener to a DOM element that does not yet exist.

```
$( '#a' ).change(function() {
    var data='<select id="b"><option>Please Select</option><option value="1">hello hello</option></select>';
        $('#second_select').html(data);
                $( '#b' ).change(function() {
                alert('hello');
                });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should bind the event to the element #b upon creation, not when the DOM is loaded.

```
<script>
    $( '#a' ).change(function() {
        var b = $('<select>',{'id':'b'}).change(function() {
            alert('hello');
        }); 
        $(b).append($('<option>').text('Please Select'));
        $('#second_select').append(b);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks :) data is returned by another php but I get what you mean.

Comment: I would recommend you to populate elements by DOM over static string. It is less error-prone and easier to keep track of events binding.